# Can't get tnoodle-lib-objc working in swift

Tags: swift, objective-c

I am coding a speedcubing timer and I am trying to get the tnoodle-lib library ([link here](https://github.com/CubeStuffs/tnoodle-lib-objc)) working with my Xcode project. So far I have managed to import everything I think, but I don't know how to actually generate the scrambles with it. Can somebody please help?

Here is what I have going on:

in my Header.h bridging file:

```
#ifndef Bridging_Header_h
#define Bridging_Header_h

#import "org/worldcubeassociation/tnoodle/scrambles/PuzzleRegistry.h"
#import "org/worldcubeassociation/tnoodle/scrambles/Puzzle.h"
#import "org/worldcubeassociation/tnoodle/svglite/Svg.h"
#import "org/worldcubeassociation/tnoodle/svglite/Dimension.h"

NSString * const SCRAMBLE = "/("NSSOrgWorldcubeassociationTnoodleScramblesPuzzleRegistry_get_THREE())"

#endif /* Bridging_Header_h */
```

In my project build settings I imported the tnoodle-lib-objc stuff like it said on the github page. What I can't figure out is how to actually use this to generate scrambles because it seems like you would do that in java, and I don't know how to transfer it from java to swift.

Comment: Funny that I've run into this. I'm the developer of the parent project (CubeTime), and tnoodle-lib-objc is developed by us. You are welcome to see how we have used this library in [CubeTime](https://github.com/CubeStuffs/CubeTime). 

I cannot provide a direct answer as your question is too broad. Please edit your post to include more information on how you have included the library and post a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Oh, you're the guy that made CubeTime, I love that timer. I have looked through the cube time code but I can't make much sense of it though, as you can probably tell I'm not a very good programmer, yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good to understand what the bridging header does. As we're using Objective-C code, we need to "bridge" this code so it can be used in Swift – this is the purpose of the bridging header. It should only act as an intermediate for the Objective-C code we need, which are the import statements.

Your bridging header should look something like this, for a very simple bare bones approach:

```cpp
#ifndef Bridging_Header_h
#define Bridging_Header_h

#import "org/worldcubeassociation/tnoodle/scrambles/PuzzleRegistry.h"
#import "org/worldcubeassociation/tnoodle/scrambles/Puzzle.h"

#endif
```

This gives us access to the tnoodle Puzzle and PuzzleRegistry components.

From here, in our Swift code – anywhere in your main program, you should be able to call the scrambler. For example:

```swift
OrgWorldcubeassociationTnoodleScramblesPuzzleRegistry.TWO.getScrambler().generateScramble()
```

`.TWO` is the scramble type, could be `.THREE`, `SQ1`, any tnoodle scramble type. If you refer to the tnoodle repo, you can see how they've defined their `Puzzle`, with methods.
Each "puzzle type" has a `.getScrambler()` method, which returns an `OrgWorldcubeassociationTnoodleScramblesPuzzle` object, where `.generateScramble()` can then be called. This will generate a scramble for for the puzzle type you've chosen.

Be wary that the returned object is an Optional, you will need to unwrap to obtain the String.

Comment: Well, I tried this and I get an error, "Cannot find 'OrgWorldcubeassociationTnoodleScramblesPuzzleRegistry' in scope". I am assuming this is because I didn't import tnoodle-lib-objc correctly. The only difference I can find between how the tutorial said to import and how I imported is the linking, I linked a direct path to libjre_net.a rather than -ljre_net which gave me an error. Is this why, and if so how would I fix it?

Comment: What do you have under xcodeproj > TARGETS > (your app name) > Linking > Other Linker Flags

Comment: it is -ltnoodle, -ljre_core, -ljre_util, -ljre_net, and -ljre_security. Also, I noticed that the GitHub repo says it is deprecated, so if there is no way to get it to work I am totally fine to wait, this is just a project to get better at programming apps, it isn't anything super important.

Comment: We've deprecated the repo as we've now switched to using a more native binary through graalvm – the old repo still works. Unfortunately I can't help you out here as I'm not entirely sure what the issue here is. If you've followed all the steps, imported and linked correctly, it doesn't seem like you should be running into any issues. Sorry!

Comment: that's fine, will the new library be one of the things you can import inside xcode as an extension?

Comment: Not sure what you mean "import as an extension". If you mean a package, I don't believe there is enough demand for this to be a standalone swift package. The new library will be used within the project as a dynamic library, but will require essentially the same number of steps.

Comment: okay, thats fine